# Can not save bundle product

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I want create a bundle product,but when I click the save button,nothing happend,not saving,no error message,nothing in the console。can anyone help? thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is clear on what it means.

You can disable dynamic pricing in the options by Setting **Dynamic Price** value to **No**.
And after that, you can perform adding new **Bundle products** without encountering that kind of error message.

Comment: error message? you mean customeable option? I don't need that option。And I disable Dynamic Price still can't save。

Comment: yeah, the error message in customizable options.

Comment: sometimes  I use checkbox in the 'input type' can save,sometimes not ,and use radio buttons never work..

Comment: did you try creating new bundle product with dynamic price set No first before saving?

Comment: I disable Dynamic Price,still not work...

Comment: I just tryed,still cannot save

Comment: that's strange ..

Comment: did you try reindexing?

Comment: I try reindexing not long ago,after that not add anything to system,ok I'll try it again

Comment: okay try anything..you can also try di:compile if ever you made some modifications with some custom module

Comment: I try the reindexing,di:compile..etc，still can not save :(,so stragnge

Comment: can you check in your logs if oyu got some errors ?

Comment: no errors,The save button any request,so I thing is js error,but no error either

Comment: I'll disable some modules and try again,think you for your time

Comment: It's ok now , when compile there are some errors ,I never noticed,I fixed the code error,and reindex and compile,then ok.thanks very much